# pig configuration spring

Tags: apache-pig

Have you come across configuring and running pig jobs using spring?

Because lately i was trying to integrate spring and pig during which i couldn't get `hdp:pig-runner` and `hdp:pig-factory` tags running. It was giving me error saying " cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'hdp:pig- factory'." . I tried all possible ways but couldn't come up with a solution. Could anyone of you please help.. Even any small suggestions will be helpful.

The schemas I used are

```
<beans xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop" <xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing angle bracket on the `<beans>` element.

Comment: no actually i just copy pasted few part of my configuration.so missed the angle bracket. In my program the angle bracket is there as i am using Eclipse IDE it provides me tags whenever i create a tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still facing this problem..

First of all you have 2 spring-hadoop.xsd declared in your configuration file.

Also, did you add the necessary libraries. As in, if you use maven, have you added the necessary dependencies?